# How to test ContentProvider with ProviderTestRule in kotlin

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-testing, android-context, android-junit

I have implemented a ContentProvider that uses a Room database to store the data. The implementation is done in kotlin and it follows the same pattern shown in this [Google example](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/master/PersistenceContentProviderSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/contentprovidersample/provider/SampleContentProvider.java).
The ContentProvider works fine when used in an app. Now I want to write some tests and I am relying on ProviderTestRule for doing so. The configuration I have seems fine, but unfortunately I am getting the following exception, which looks like some initialisation is missing and then the context is not available.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at androidx.test.rule.provider.DelegatingContext.getSystemService(DelegatingContext.java:277)
at androidx.room.RoomDatabase$JournalMode.resolve(RoomDatabase.java:517)
at androidx.room.RoomDatabase$Builder.build(RoomDatabase.java:943)
```

I wasn't able to find any example of how to test this scenario. Any hint would be really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

`ProviderTestRule` internally uses `DelegatingContext`, which is a wrapper around the application context that purposely limits its capabilities.

From the source code you can see that `context.getSystemService` is stubbed out, throwing `UnsupportedOperationException` most of the time:

```java
  /**
   * This method only supports retrieving {@link android.app.AppOpsManager}, which is needed by
   * {@link android.content.ContentProvider#attachInfo}.
   */
  @Override
  public Object getSystemService(@NonNull String name) {
    checkArgument(!TextUtils.isEmpty(name), "name cannot be empty or null");
    // getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE) is only used in ContentProvider#attachInfo for
    // API level >= 19.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT
        && Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE.equals(name)) {
      return context.getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
    }
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
  }
```

I have no clear explaination why they forbid access to system services for `ProviderTestRule` in the first place.
Unfortunately, it seems that Room requires access to the `ActivityManager` in order to find the most appropriate `JournalMode`.

What you can try to workaround the situation:

1. Force the `JournalMode` of you Room database to `JournalMode.WRITE_AHEAD_LOGGING` (or `JournalMode.TRUNCATE`), or
2. If it did not solve the situation, you'd have to write your own `ProviderTestRule` that uses the real application context to and allow access to the desired system service.